# 2D Array of Pointers -> Classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I am having problems with my constructor in class *World*.

I created a 2D array with pointers where each entry in the array is of type *Organism*, hence the line of code:

```
Organism* grid[20][20];
```

When I run my program, I only see

```
hello
```

and after that, I get a message saying that my program has stopped working. I'm pretty sure it's the line of code

```
grid[i][j]->symbol = ' ';
```

that's causing the problem. Just to see what would happen, I changed that line to

```
grid[i][j];
```

and didn't get any errors. But, the moment I put *->*, I seem to get errors.

Is there a reason why my program stops working after I put *->*? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Organism
{
public: 
    char symbol;
};

class World
{
public:
    World();

private:
    Organism* grid[20][20];
};


int main()
{
    World world;
    return 0;
}


World::World()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            cout << "hello" << endl;
            grid[i][j]->symbol = ' ';
            cout << "here" << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You have an array of pointers to `Organism` that don't point to anything.

Comment: Yeah, how is the `->` operator supposed to dereference a pointer if there's no memory allocated for the object?

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't fully understand pointers.

Comment: @enochsoccer a pointer tells you whereabouts in memory something else can be found. It does not imply any sort of ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of *pointers* to `Organism`.

Pointers can *not* hold any data other than an address. They can only point to memory (that holds data).

**Your array's pointers does not point to anything**, thats why you get *undefined behaviour* when you try to assign data to where the pointers point at.

You need to allocate memory for your array.

```
Organism grid[20][20]; // Create an array of objects (not pointers).
/* ... */
grid[i][j].symbol = ' ';
```

Same using **dynamic memory**:

```
class World {
public:
    World();
    ~World();                                // Rule of Three.
    World(const World&) = delete;            // Rule of Three.
    World& operator=(const World&) = delete; // Rule of Three.
private:
    Organism** grid;
};

World::World() {
    grid = new Organism*[20]; // Allocate memory to point to.
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
        grid[i] = new Organism[20]; // Allocate memory to point to.
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
            cout << "hello" << endl;
            grid[i][j].symbol = ' ';
            cout << "here" << endl;
        }
    }
}

// Destructor needed to deallocate memory (otherwise it will leak).
World::~World()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 20; ++i) {
        delete[] grid[i];
    }
    delete[] grid;
}
```

Now you can see how complicated it gets when using dynamic memory and why it's recommended to prefer to use *automatic storage duration* (i.e. create objects, not pointers and `new`/`delete`).

Even better is to use a container from the *standard library* for storing your elements as e.g. `std::vector`.

**Related:**

- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/873025)

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, but now, I get the error:
invalid abstract type 'Organism' for 'grid'

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Organism* grid[20][20];
```

To

```
Organism  grid[20][20];
```

and use

```
grid[i][j].symbol = '';
```

instead of

```
grid[i][j]->symbol = '';
```

and add a default constructor to Organism

```
class Organism
{
   Organism();
   ...
}
```

or make Organism a struct

```
struct Oranism
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Now, I get the error:
invalid abstract type 'Organism' for 'grid'

Comment: i guess you should add a default constructor for Organism or change it from class to struct.